# Is there a way to check for asyn functions called directly without await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

Often times I accidentally call an asynchronous function directly like so

```
let get_users;
let users;

/*
 * @return data on success and null otherwise
*/
get_users = async function (){
    let users;

    users = await $.ajax({...});

    return users;
}

users = get_users();

if (users === null){
    console.log ('Fail');
}
else{
    console.log ('Success');
}
```

This will write `Success` every time because the returned `promise` is not null and it is quite a nightmare to debug. I can go through and append something to all of my 500+ asynchronous functions (eg. `foo.bar_async ()`) and then use grep to find all cases where a `*_async` function was called without the `await` command, but that is very hard and very ugly. Is there a better way to debug this (NOTE I do not believe JSHint can handle this, especially when files are loaded as modules)?

Comment: is it nodeJs or javascript in browser?

Comment: @AmirSaleem, javascript in browser (I can add the tag if you tell me which is most relevant)

Comment: If you're unwilling to do it manually, you can use Find and Replace (keyboard shortcut: Ctrl+H) on most applications.

Comment: @puk No, I was just clearing this. Javascript is the most relevant tag for this question.

Comment: For the unhandled promise warnings and stack trace, you can use the following https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunhandledrejection